# Knockout.js mapping plugin throws error when using "observe" option

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

When trying to do this:

```
var objToMap = {
    a: 1,
    b: [
        {
            c: {
                d: 1
            }
        }
    ]
};
var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(objToMap, { observe: ["a"] })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22Bjj/

The docs say that I can use "observe" alone, without specifying "copy".

This is a simplified example, in my real app I have lots of object to copy and only one to observe so using only "observe" is the best for me.

Comment: Please try it out with the latest version from github because your code seems to work with it: http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/G6zkd/

Comment: Seems it doesn't... How did you come to this conclusion? I updated the fiddle and just dumped the source to html http://jsfiddle.net/G6zkd/1/

Comment: In my fiddle there is no object is not a function in the console... using the latest version from github...

Comment: You are correct, I took the wrong version. Thanks, if you want you can post it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a quite old version of the KO mapping plugin: 2.3.5 while the latest official version is v2.4.1

But this a latest released version is also containing the bug what you are experiencing:

['observe' mapping options doesn't work with sub-object](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/issues/137)

This was fixed but not released yet so you need to use the absolute latest version of the plugin directly from [github](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/master/knockout.mapping.js).